# Kth from the last element in a list using golang

Tags: list, recursion, go, null

I have the code to find the kth from the last element in a list in golang. I wrote a recursive function. When it reaches the end of the list, it will return the count as 1 and increments in further returns. When the count == k then return the node value. But I am getting 'nil pointer dereference' error. Could anyone help me in this?

```
package main    
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

var sMap map[int]bool

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
        l.PushBack(i)
    }    
    kFromLastElemRec := findKFromLastRecr(l.Front(), 3, WrapObj{0})
    fmt.Println(kFromLastElemRec.Value.(int))    
}
//Object to store the count 
type WrapObj struct {
    count int
}
//ERROR
//recursive function to find the kth from last element
func findKFromLastRecr(head *list.Element, k int, wrapper WrapObj) *list.Element {
    if head == nil {
        return nil
    }

    resNode := findKFromLastRecr(head.Next(), k, wrapper)
    wrapper.count = (wrapper.count) + 1
    if wrapper.count == k {
        return head
    }
    return resNode
}
```

Comment: Your wrapper is just a copy in each of the calls of your function and `wrapper.count` is with value 1 in all stacks. Try changing WrapObj to pointer maybe? Also maybe there's something I'm missing, but this logic seems too complex. Can't you just get the `Len()` of the list and substract the "K from last", then iterate to the desired element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a pointer to `WrapObj` to the `findKFromLastRecr()` function.

Similar to the languages in the C family, everything in Go is passed by value. That is, a function always gets a copy of the thing being passed, as if there were an assignment statement assigning the value to the parameter.

For instance, passing a `WrapObj` value to a function makes a copy of the `WrapObj`, but not the `WrapObj` it points to.

Therefore, without a pointer to `WrapObj`, each `findKFromLastRecr()` function gets a copy of `WrapObj` and the increase can not be shared by the outer `findKFromLastRecr()` functions.

It could be useful to check the [pointers](http://www.golang-book.com/8/index.htm) section from golang-book.

```
package main    
import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

var sMap map[int]bool

func main() {
    l := list.New()
    for i := 1; i < 100; i++ {
        l.PushBack(i)
    }    
    kFromLastElemRec := findKFromLastRecr(l.Front(), 3, &WrapObj{0})
    fmt.Println(kFromLastElemRec.Value.(int))    
}
//Object to store the count 
type WrapObj struct {
    count int
}
//ERROR
//recursive function to find the kth from last element
func findKFromLastRecr(head *list.Element, k int, wrapper *WrapObj) *list.Element {
    if head == nil {
        return nil
    }

    resNode := findKFromLastRecr(head.Next(), k, wrapper)
    wrapper.count = (wrapper.count) + 1
    if wrapper.count == k {
        return head
    }
    return resNode
}
```

Output

```
97
```

Comment: This helps me.Thanks. Could you explain me this. I used the same way in another function it works. should it always be the case to pass the pointer?

Comment: @DineshAppavoo, I updated the answer and briefly tried to explain it. I hope it helps.